# Code Review with Visual Studio 2013

Tags: .net, visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2013

Has anyone used Code Review Tool in VS 2013?

I cant see how to really get an iterative code review process - i.e if I load up 40 files and my reviewer makes comments on 25 off them then I go away and complete the work I have to upload a completely new code review and the new review has no context as too any of the comments made in previous review - unless I am missing something?

Comment: I would like to urge readers to vote to re-open. It does _not_ fall under the "recommend or find a tool, library or resource" criteria mentioned in the reason it was put on hold. This is a very specific question about using VS2013's code review feature, a question that has discombobulated me and many of my coworkers since we started using the VS code review capability.

Comment: @MichaelSorens - agreed - perhaps MS will re-look at this for next version of VS - you could try this link - http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9ef817b4-2c6d-4213-8b08-5be48f9d91b9 and see if it adds anything - it does require a licence for more than 1 project with more than 3 Deevelopers though

Comment: Michael@MErickson.com certainly agrees, the TFS code review process seems to be very limiting and awkward to use. The awkwardness most likely can be overcome with experience, but the tool does not seem to provide capability to manage multiple review cycles, which is very common in any group. I currently do not have a clue how to revise an existing review.

Answer (score 4):

You have decided to use a different product instead but below is how it works for Visual Studio Code View

1) You make changes and set it out to the reviewer to review
2) The reviewer reviews it and send back some comments
3) You receive the code review back with comments.

Each code review request results in a new work item creation, with a task created for the reviewer, which is a child work item. If you click on the "Open Query" link beneath code review, you can get a list of all requests and their responses. Enough information to collate changes I would think.

Have a look at http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/get-code-reviewed-vs.aspx

Also there is a brilliant video on channel 9 about the feature

http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2012/2-003

Comment: Have not reviewed the video link but the article link only outlines a very simplistic idealized code review and does not address the question that was asked.

Comment: Not to say I disagree with your comment that the process could be "discombobulated", since with new new version of TFS client, the interface seems much less intuitive and correspondingly harder and slower to use and get used to, but can you provide more detail in what your process is? According to this document "Once the changes are checked in, as you can see here, the Code Review request (ID 1619) is associated to the changeset." http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mvpawardprogram/archive/2012/09/04/new-code-review-feature-in-visual-studio-2012.aspx

Comment: I find nothing about code reviewing in the [Channel9](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2012/2-003) video mentioned. The video is an hour long, a time stamp would be appreciated.